# how to add python to system dependency on win7?

Tags: python, django, installation

i've got a problem when i'm doing dev

I managed to use
python manage.py runserver in a CMD shell
but the system cant find python

How could I add python to the system dependency to make the commandline work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two basic ways you can do this in Windows.

**Setting the PATH in the `cmd` shell**

The first way is only local to the `CMD` shell you are currently in, and will have to be done again if you opened a new shell.

You can set your `PATH` to include the directory where `python.exe` is located.

In your CMD shell you can do:

`set PATH=%PATH%;C:\path\to\python\install`

So if Python was installed in `C:\Python27`, you would do this:

`set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Python27`

**Setting the environment for your user throughout Windows**

Alternatively, you can set your `PATH` permanently by changing the environment variable in Windows. Setting this will affect the rest of your Windows environment.

1. Right click "My Computer"
2. Select "Properties"
3. Click the "Advanced" tab in the new window.
4. Click on the "Environment Variables" button.
5. Edit the variable named `PATH`

Information about doing the latter at Microsoft: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310519

Comment: I think you under emphasized that if you use the former option, you have to do it *every* time.  At least, that's how mine works.

Comment: Yes, I should add that the first choice is transient. Thanks!

Comment: I also append `.PY;.PYW` to my PATHEXT environment variable so I don't have to type "python" before the script name every time I want to execute one. Windows knows how to launch Python files through the file associations set-up by installing Python. See fuller explanation [here](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/command_line.shtml#pathext).